# how to create a side menu which appears in all article in jooma

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I want to create a side menu which appears along with article. I have created a side menu. But if i click on one menu item only the article is appearing. menu is not coming.

Comment: Do you mean only on all articles or do you mean on all pages?  What pages is your menu module assigned to right now (all, all except, some specific pages, none)?

Comment: @Elin There is a main menu called Division..Under that there is a submenu called "Nutrition". This submenu has a sidemenu which contain three links..like introuduction,key personnel and Research. So if i click on introudction only the article is coming and the sidemenu is not appearing. So if i want to go to Key personnel I have to press the back button. How to reslove this

Comment: When you say the submenu has a "side menu" do you mean that the menu as a whole has three levels? And you want to just show the third level when you click on the article?

Comment: @Elin Kindly check the link http://sjri.res.in/ctintro  .. I need the same concept in my site

Comment: Please add the detail to your question. Right now the question does not have detail enough to be answered. Don't put details in comments.

Comment: You need to create a second  menu module that only shows level 2 (this is all detailed in the options in the module parameters). Place that module in the position you want. Set it to display on all but the home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you need to assign your article to a **menu item** and connect your **side menu module** to the **menu item** just created. If you want to hide that **menu item** so it is not visible on your **main menu** then create a new menu (called for example hidden-menu) and assign the **menu item** to it. This hidden menu does not need to be assign to a module to work. Hope i made myself clear :)